# Watir ... difference between sleep and wait

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Is there any notable difference between

```
sleep 10
```

and

```
wait_until(10)
```

They both seem to do the same thing: wait 10 seconds then proceed to the next step

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`sleep` just does nothing for the specified time. `wait_until` [takes a block](http://rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/WaitHelper:wait_until). It waits until the block evaluates to true or times out. If no block is given they act the same.